# How do I prevent from writing a number that is already written?

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I prevent the user from writing a number that already exists in an array?
I tried this :

```
int[] number = new int[5];
for ( int i=0; i<number.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Write a number : );
    number[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int getindex = Array.IndexOf(number, number[i]);
    if (number[i] == number[getindex])
        Console.WriteLine("This number already exists");
}
```

But at the moment when I write it for the first time, it says that it already exists, so it isn't working.

Comment: Please post compiling code!

Comment: Use a [HashSet<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

Comment: That Array.IndexOf() call searches the entire array, not just the part that was already entered.  So you could never enter 0.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: remember the numbers you have used and dont write it if you have.. you tell us..

Comment: or you could fix your logic here and *not* store the number in the array until *after* you've tested for it's existence in the array?

Comment: @maccettura Do not edit code in posts! Formatting/changing whitespace is one thing, but actively adding or subtracting `{` is not. You can inadvertently add bugs.

Comment: @FrankerZ nothing in my edit made the code change functionality.  I added `{}` to the if to make it read better.  Unless you have found a massive flaw in the C# compiler that makes it function differently?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var number = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Write a number : ");
    int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (number.Contains(x))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This number already exists");
        i--; // retry for this index
    }
    else
    {
        number[i] = x;
    }
}
```

Try something like this if you do not want to use a HashSet.

Comment: HashSet is faster than this, and the appropriate type to use.  Why does your answer provide a benefit to the OP?  Why is using a HashSet something they would/should want to avoid?

Comment: True, I'd rather use the HashSet, but I wanted to show that it is possible to do it with the existing data structures.

Comment: @maccettura We didn't learn HashSet still so I am not allowed to use it

Comment: ohh this looks familiar ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using a hashset, For every new number, check.

If it already exist inside the hashset, ignore it

else add it to the hash set and print it

```
int[] numbers = new int[100];

HashSet<int> uniqueNums = new HashSet<int>();
for (int i=0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    bool isNew = uniqueNums.Add(number);
    if(!isNew) {
      Console.WriteLine("This number already exists");
    } 
}
```

Edit: Thanks to @maccettura for this tip, we don't even need contain method

**Why this solution?**

- It is cleaner, you don't have to care about indices.
- It is faster, in O(1) you will get your lookup while iterating means an ugly O(n)
- It is a very clear use case for hash sets.

Comment: This is quite minimalistic. You should post some code that shows, what you´ve mentioned avove.

Comment: The answer is right, but you need to put much more effort into it.  You have added no extra benefit over a simple comment.

Comment: exactly, if you want to jack points from a commenter, then you must therefore go the extra mile, stackoverflow 101.

Comment: I'm currently writing the code :) But I didn't have access to C# editor. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @AhmedKamal Check out [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), makes writing quick answers easy

Comment: @AhmedKamal your logic is a little obtuse, remember that the [.Add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns a bool value, true indicating if the value was added, or false indicating that the value already exists.  You might want to simplify your logic a bit.

Comment: @maccettura
Thanks for the tip, updated the answer !

Comment: @AhmedKamal you can even take it one further and skip the allocation of `isNew` and just put the `uniqueNums.Add(number)` in the `if` statement

Comment: @EndritShabani I don't think you are allowed to use SO to get answers to your homework  ;)

Comment: @EndritShabani the question is not clear about not being allowed to use some (standard) classes...

Comment: @AhmedKamal is not homework I am just learning and  its a challenge I found on internet , and since I didn't know how to do it I asked but people here think that everything has to do with homeworks

Answer (score 0):

> But at the moment when I write it for the first time it says that it already exist , so it isn't working .

You put the number into the array, then you check whether it is there! Of course it is there, you just put it there. See these twolines:

```
number[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (number[i] == number[getindex])
```

you are still at position `i`

> How can I prevent user from writing a number that already exist in a array ?

actually you need first to prevent yourself from writing before you check the existence by using a local variable to catch the input:

```
int localnumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

then [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx) will return -1 if the number is not present

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The zero-based index of the first occurrence of value in the entire array, if found; otherwise, –1.

so you can check for this:

```
int getindex = Array.IndexOf(number, localnumber );
if (getindex == -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This number already exists Try again please");
    // then you count i one position back so that the next valid number is inserted on the correct position
    i--;
}
else
{
    number[i] = localnumber;
}
```

Comment: ah I see it's downvote_without_any_comments day... so where did I fail? Am I supposed not to encourage such questions by posting this answer?